# How to convert a signal from frequency domain to time domain?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Is it right this relationship?

$y(\omega)=A(\omega)\cdot e^{j \phi(\omega)}$
can be written as
$y(\omega)=y(t)=A(\omega) \cdot \sin[\omega  t + \phi(\omega)]$

Because I got several couples of amplitude and phases, each couple associated to a certain frequency, so that:

$\omega_1 \rightarrow (A_1,\phi_1)$

$\omega_2 \rightarrow (A_2,\phi_2)$

and so on.

Assuming that in a certain time instant, $t=1$, the frequency is equal to $\omega_1$, how can I build that signal in the time domain? Is it right to state:

$y(t_1) = y(\omega_1)=A_1 \cdot e^{j \phi_1}=A_1 \cdot \sin(\omega_1 t_1 + \phi_1)$

or not?

Comment: Your question is not well posed and shows lack of understanding of fundamental concepts of Fourier analysis. Statements like $y(t)=y(\omega)$ make no sense.

Comment: It is meant for a particular frequency, so it is a numerical value.